# Remove List elements that are same

Tags: c#, linq, directory

I currently have two lists of Directory Info. Candidatelist & VersionList. VersionList being a sublist of candidate list. I'm trying to remove all the elements from candidate list that appear in version list. So if canadidate list has 177 elements and version list has 77 then we have 100 elements left in candidate list. To be more explicit of whats inside the list. Each element correspons to a directory folder name who has a name and a parent folder name. It is possible that the directory name has duplicates but diffeerent parents. I tried doing this but I'm not necesarily getting the correct result Take a look:

```
candidateList.RemoveAll(x => versionslist.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name) && versionslist.Any(y => y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name));
      return candidateList;
```

Comment: `I tried doing this but I'm necesarily getting the correct result ` So what's the problem?

Comment: You are saying "I'm trying to remove all the elements from version list that appear in canadidate list", but your code removes elements from candidateList. You have it backwards.

Comment: @wicher Visser I meant to say I'm trying to remove all elements in candidate list that are in version list

Comment: @PhillipsJP, .net `DirectoryInfo` class has `FullName` property. why not use it to compare list items?

Comment: @ash I can't because yes they are both list of direcoryinfos but their full paths are not necessarily the same how the code was done. The two lists were constructed in different ways but their parents name and actual folder names do match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is not constraining business requirements to a single version list item. It's making the two queries separately. It's saying:

1. Are there any versionList items where the Name matches the current candidateList item name

If yes:

2. Are there any versionList items where the Parent.Name matches the current candidateList item Parent.Name

If yes, remove the item from the candidate list. Instead, you should be querying for a versionList item that meets both requirements pieces at the same time.

```
candidateList.RemoveAll(x => versionslist.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name));
  return candidateList;
```

This is now saying:

Are there any versionList items where the `Name` and `Parent.Name` matches the current candidateList item `Name` and `Parent.Name`, respectively.

Comment: @PhillipsJP Compare your query to the query I posted. Do you see the difference? This is the same as the answer you upvoted from Paarth and edited by zx485.

Comment: I believe this did the trick I'm still checking on some stuff @Larry hold up

Comment: Glad to hear @PhillipsJP

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you want to remove all the elements from version list that appear in canadidate list. I think then your syntax should be like:

```
VersionList.RemoveAll(x => candidateList.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name);
      return VersionList;
```

if it is vice versa, then use

```
 candidateList.RemoveAll(x => VersionList.Any(y => y.Name == x.Name && y.Parent.Name == x.Parent.Name);
          return candidateList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use IEnumerable.Except() method with custom IEqualityComparer:

```
var differences = candidateList.Except(versionList, new DirectoryInfoComparer());
```

---

The EqualityComparer could look like this:

```
public class DirectoryInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<DirectoryInfo>   
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<DirectoryInfo>.Equals(DirectoryInfo x, DirectoryInfo y)
    {            
        return (x.Name == y.Name) && (x.Parent.Name == y.Parent.Name);        
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<DirectoryInfo>.GetHashCode(DirectoryInfo obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
            return 0;               

        return obj.GetHashCode();       
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can use method ExceptBy() from MoreLinq